# Why are these duplicate cases?

Tags: java, string, char, switch-statement, case

I am trying to convert a phone number that is written in letters, into its true numeric form. I have this switch statement inside of a for loop that looks at each char of the string, but eclipse is saying that I have duplicate cases ('G' | 'H' | 'I', 'J' | 'K' | 'L', 'M' | 'N' | 'O') and I don't understand why?

```
switch(parts[1].charAt(i)){
   case 'A' | 'B' | 'C' : number.concat("2"); break; 
   case 'D' | 'E' | 'F' : number.concat("3"); break; 
   case 'G' | 'H' | 'I' : number.concat("4"); break; 
   case 'J' | 'K' | 'L' : number.concat("5"); break; 
   case 'M' | 'N' | 'O' : number.concat("6"); break; 
   case 'P' | 'Q' | 'R' | 'S' : number.concat("7"); break; 
   case 'T' | 'U' | 'V' : number.concat("8"); break; 
   case 'W' | 'X' | 'Y' | 'Z' : number.concat("9"); break; 
}
```

Comment: Because that's not how you do multiple cases. Check your Java syntax: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: This is the kind of thing that happens when someone tries to *guess* the syntax of a construct ... and they guess wrong.  Next time, try checking the syntax in a book or a tutorial.  Always a good idea when you are new to a language.

Comment: I understand how to use a switch, including fall through, I guess I just don't understand what bit wise operations do.

Comment: If you don't know `|`, pretend it's a `+`. Either way, the switch won't test for the individual letters, because its testing for the combined numeric value, losing the information about what letters were used to create the combined value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hilariously, I think I know what's going on.

When you do `'A' | 'B'`, you're doing bitwise-OR on the *byte values* of A and B. Your IDE is detecting that a few of the resulting values are equivalent. This *definitely* isn't what you want to do.

What you want is more like:

```
case 'A':
case 'B':
case 'C':
    number.concat("2");
    break;
case 'D':
    [...]
```

and so on.

See "SwitchDemo2" at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html for more info.

Verified (using Python):

```
>>> ord('G') | ord('H') | ord('I')
79
>>> ord('J') | ord('K') | ord('L')
79
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, but would you be so kind as to offer an explanation on bit wise operations and why my thinking was wrong?

Comment: No problem!
A bitwise OR is a way of saying "set all bits these two binary numbers have in common." So, for example, `0101 | 0010 == 0111`. With me so far?
OK. So, to the computer (and Java), 'A' is just another binary number (specifically, 65 = 0b1000001). When you `|` `A` and `B` together, you get `0b1000011`. Given this, `'G' | 'H' | 'I' == 0b1000111 | 0b1001000 | 0b1001001 == 0b1001111 == 79`, and `'J' | 'K' | 'L' == 0b1001010 | 0b1001011 | 0b1001100 == 0b1001111 == 79`.

Comment: Your IDE, Eclipse, was attempting to optimize by doing these operations for you, and detecting that their results were equivalent.
Your _thinking_ was fine; you were just using the incorrect syntax. Googling for something like "java multiple case syntax" would have helped. It's not wrong to ask for help, but there are plenty of references out there. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: (Remember to accept the answer -- to this and future questions -- if this helped you.)

Comment: Okay, now (I know it has nothing to do with a switch) but say in an if statement `|` and `||` are nothing alike then?

Comment: Yes, I would have earlier, but it has that stupid wait limit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39534/discussion-between-christian-ternus-and-lampwins)

Comment: @ChristianTernus This is not an Eclipse thing. It's not an  optimization or warning. It's a bona fide Java error which any Java compiler is required to complain about. [JLS §14.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11): "No two of the case constant expressions associated with a switch statement may have the same value."

Comment: @Boann that said, your _editor_ is certainly not required to evaluate bitwise OR statements for you. That's what I mean by optimization.

Comment: Yes, it is. It's required that each case value is a constant expression. I.e., one that can be reduced to a single value at compile time. And it does have to do that evaluation to ensure that no two of the cases have the same value.

Comment: Sure, your _compiler_ is required to do that, but your _editor_ (emacs, for example) certainly isn't. The fact that it does so is a convenient checking function, just like syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 5):

The `|` character in your code is acting as a [bitwise OR operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) use `switch` fallthrough instead

```
switch(parts[1].charAt(i)){
    case 'A':
    case 'B':
    case 'C':
        number.concat("2");
    break;
    ...
```

Look at the results of these bytevalues

```
System.out.println('G' | 'H' | 'I');
System.out.println('J' | 'K' | 'L');
```

both print 79

Quoting from [JLS 14.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11)

> No two of the case constant expressions associated with a switch statement may have the same value.

- this is why the compiler complains

Read the [switch tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) to see how fallthrough is used

Answer (score 0):

Each character has a binary equivalent.  For example, 'G' has the binary value 01000111.  When you apply the bitwise OR operator '|', you match each of the 8 binary bits producing a 1 if either is a 1 or 0 if they are both 0.  So 'G' | 'H' would be equivalent to matching the bits of 01000111 with 01001000 (the binary representation of H - they go in order starting with 'A' at 01000001).  The result is 01001111, which when converted to decimal gives you 79.
If you go through the manual exercise, you will indeed find that 'G' | 'H' | 'I' is equivalent to 'J' | 'K' | 'L'.

Comment: As stated in the other answers?